# Radius on beveled curve incorrect

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

The bevel depth (the radius of the tube) is set to 9cm but it actually isn't when compared to the background grid. This is is confirmed by importing it into sketchup and scaling it to the proper units it turns out the radius is only around 2.286cm. This problem only shows up on certain projects. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

(sorry that I can't upload the file, it's a long story)

Comment: If you can't upload the file, make a minimal example that shows your issue.

Comment: Usually problems with incorrect measurements are due to objects not having their scale applied - in other words you are viewing the object in a scaled state, but measuring its original state. You can press Ctrl A to Apply Scale so the scaled state will then be registered as the original state, and there will no longer be a discrepancy.

Comment: I think @Mentalist is correct. Was the object scaled in object mode?
Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the *Curve Radius* property.

Under *Edit Mode* each vertex has a *Radius* value that acts as a scaling factor for the bevel width. If the bevel width is $9$ units, and bevel $0.5$ then you will end up with a bevel of $4.5$ units. It will also affect the scale of bevel objects.

You can control per *Vertex Radius* from the *Properties Shelf* in *Edit Mode* under the coordinates boxes or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for proportionally changing the values. You can also override all selected vertex at once and set an absolute value with the *Set Curve Radius Operator* (Space Bar menu).

Also check the object scale in *Object Mode* and make sure it is $1$, if not apply it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* then and afterwards go through the steps described above, since applying uniform scales to curve objects also affects per vertex radius values.

Also see [Curve Bevel function, scale?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564)

Comment: Okay, I did all that and now everything is at 1, it turns out my scale was at 2.54 or something like that which is coincidentally close to the cm to inches conversion rate.