# How to change radius/weight of curve bezier?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]
try scaling, change radius, but it`s don`t work
[scene link](http://blender-3d.ru/forum/go.php?url=aHR0cHM6Ly95YWRpLnNrL2QvX0VDb0dMQm5GNUtlY2c=)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radius on beveled curve incorrect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86873/radius-on-beveled-curve-incorrect)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to apply the scale of your object because you must have scaled it in *Object* mode and it deforms it, so select it and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

About the radius, you can either change the radius of the curve vertices or change the radius of the bevel.

For the curve vertices radius, go in *Edit* mode, select the vertices and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, or in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel (on the right of the *3D View*) > *Item* > *Transform* > *Radius*.

For the bevel radius, go in *Edit* mode, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Geometry* > and change the *Depth*.