# Curve Path Flat?

Tags: bezier-curves

Quick question, why is my Curve: Path flat in some sections and circular in others? How can I make it round again and how did I make it do this in the first place? A quick run down of using it to make hand railing for machinery with less faces would be awesome.

This simpler, flatter shape uses a lot less faces than the normal Curve Path does and would be great if only it would stay consistently roundish around the corners. The up and along section over the back of the picture is round, at the first bend it flattens and stays flat the rest of the way.

Thanks all.

[image]

Comment: Check radius https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129312/2214 you can learn more about curves here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58567/2214

Comment: Ahhh dammit, missed that one. Thank you so much! :)