# Bezier curve taper not working

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am trying to make a wine glass, exploiting its axial symmetry.

I have a bezier curve `spine` (a line) which I have bevelled using another bezier curve `bevel` (a bezier circle).

I then applied a wine glass shaped bezier curve `outer` as taper to spine.

However, `spine` only reflects the bevelling and not the taper. (looks like a right cylinder)

What's wrong?

[image]
*fig1: On left the bevel curve, in the middle the spine and on right the taper curve*

---

I have tried rescaling `bevel` and repositioning `outer` to no avail.

[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174837/2-8-curve-bevel-and-taper-scaling-issues/174849#174849

Answer (score 0):

Select the upright glass section then apply a Screw modifier and choose the Y axis in the properties.

[image]

Comment: the question is regarding debugging the taper property of bezeir curve...else i did it using Spin tool, yours works too.