# My text gets really big when I am trying to extrude it

Tags: extrude, text-object

I have tried to look at tutorials but none of them have worked.

I am trying to extrude this text
[image: normal text]

but every time I extrude the text even a little bit this happens and there is no end on ether side (i have it extruded to .01m)
[image: extrusion issue]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86873/radius-on-beveled-curve-incorrect/86903#86903