# Extruded spline is twice scale of resulting bevel

Tags: transforms, bevel, path, splines

I've drawn an architrave profile and swept it around another rectangular path using the Bevel command. It looks great, except the resulting form's cross section is about half the size of the original profile. I've applied the scale of both (so both at 1), yet there's still a size difference. Changing the scale of the original profile also affects the resulting form, but it's always half the size. What might I have missed?

[image: profile and result]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86873/radius-on-beveled-curve-incorrect https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe

Comment: Close but still not there - everything everywhere is set to 1, yet it's still smaller. Interestingly, my path curve was generated by duplicating an edge loop on my door mesh object, separating it and converting to a curve. However, when I make a new path curve from scratch, I don't have the issue - it's somehow pulling a random scale through from the door mesh? But the door mesh object had all scales applied...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't skip number 4  from first link? Curve weight per vertex ...

Comment: please provide blend file so we don't have to guess

Comment: Thanks all, this is much appreciated. Google Drive link to download blend file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/16dUZ5stRAnhMpjN2NPFNy6vskMt5Iqgj/view?usp=sharing. Pretty sure I didn't skip stage 4; if I highlight a node in edit mode, the Radius value is between Weight and Tilt? In which case they're all set to 1 as far as I can see?

Comment: At the end ... the third Duarte's link was the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**
It is caused by curve set as **3D type** ... profile orientation is calculated as average of previous and next control point - in this case average from 90 deg = 45 deg ... as you can see in screen.

[image]

This is typical issue, clearly visible when you use simple circle shape or just Bevel in curve properties.

**Solution**
Switch curve to **2D type**.
(*Properties Editor > Curve Data Properties > Shape > 2D*)

It means rotate object for top view Apply Rotation, switch to 2D, in Object mode rotate back to Front view.

[image]

BTW ... Your object "New Path" generates the same deformation on Y axis as the "Door Path" ... there is no differences (other than I had to change Tilt to fix direction).

**Alternatively** (in this specific case) you can solve the issue for 3D type by **Split** operator ... select two control point on one side and press <kbd>Y</kbd> than do the same on opposite side. So the final result is the same as 2D, but since in the corner are two points, manipulation / transformation is not so effective :)

Comment: Thank you! Still new Blender so it'll take me a while to digest this, but much appreciated. :)

Comment: One of the last weird thing in Blender :) If you would work with circle you will discover it by your self ... this one took me a time to realised to me too :) Great if brought it a bit of light :)