# how can I extrude several Bezier-curves with the exact same height?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, extrude, 2d

-in Object mode, I create those 2 Bezier-curves (the rectangle and the star) and a circle-curve
[image]

-I set all the scale for all of these three curves to 1.000

[image]

-I set the origin for each curve to its geometry

-in Object Data Properties, under the title Shape: I click on the button “2D”
-Fill Mode: Both
-Geometry: Extrude: 0.5 m
[image]

-> result/problem: every shape has a different value of extrusion

How can I get the all extruded the same height?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhKRh.jpg)
[image]
[image]

ps: I have the exact same problem when making voluminous tubes out of Bezier-curves: the extrusion value I put in the field is always the same, whereas the thickness of each tube is different.
Thank you very much for your time and effort! I appreciate it.

Comment: If you Ctrl-A  applied the object-level scale of the curves, to set their scale to 1, their previous scale might have been baked into their 'Radius' setting, to compensate. In Edit Mode, N-panel, 'Item' tab, check the Mean Radius of the control-points.

Comment: Hey Robin thanks for anwering. I guess you are referring to the tubes-problem with the "radius". Right now, I'm just worried about the extrusion of the curves. I just tried out both versions (one with and the other without Ctrl+A): it always gives me a different height/depth when it comes to the extrusion...

Comment: Hi, Thereo, Radius scales extrusion height, too ... can you share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86873/radius-on-beveled-curve-incorrect

Comment: Hi Robin, I just uploaded one of my files with the exact same problem (it's different forms/ extruded curves but the exact same problem). I'll post the link to the file here below:

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=So2LGQze" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/So2LGQze/)