# Can't make different size rings with the same volume thckness

Tags: modeling, duplicate

I´m trying to make many copies of circles and then give them the same volume thickness. But even if I put the same depth for the bevel, they all end up having different thickness. I made them with a bezier circle and then duplicating. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86903/19307 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58567/19307

Comment: Obviously you have not only duplicated the curves, but also scaled them in _Object Mode_. First of all, this would not happen if you scaled them in _Edit Mode_. But now after you did it, what you can do is apply the scale with Ctrl+A > _Apply_ > _Scale_. But in the _Apply Object Transorm_ options at the bottom left of the viewport you have to leave _Scale_ enabled but to disable _Apply Properties_, otherwise the thickness will not be reset, because then the scale will be transferred to the _Mean Radius_ of the control points. See Duarte's links for more explanations on that.