# Why does my model deforms when apply curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, path

I have the model of a snake and I want it to follow a path, it deforms like this when I apply the curve modifier

[image]
[image]

Comment: Choose another deformation axis in modifier settings, try -Z

Comment: I already tried with all deformation axis :( it deforms into a flat mesh like in the picture

Comment: have you applied the rotation and scale of your snake?

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier

Comment: Attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail inspection