# Curves and curve modifier is a nightmare

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I try to learn the basics about curves and curve modifiers. To do this, I tried to make a zipper. It was a catastrophe. Doesn't matter what tutorial i follow, the following things (one, more, or all) happening to me:

- The mesh and the curve is fram from each other
- The mesh not following the paths shape
- The mesh turning to different directions
- applying the same origin destroys everything
- Apply all transform sets the origin to the pivot of the coordinate system
- Twist
- Strange shapes

So can anybody tell wich is caused by what? I'm near to breakdown. Thanks

Comment: Whenever I have had problems with the Curve Modifier it is because I did not apply Transforms CTRL+a

Comment: As I written, I applied Transforms, and the origin jumped back to the pivot of the coordinate system.

Comment: Consider sharing your blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, so we can try to replicate your issue :)

Comment: I didn't know There is a place for this! Thanks! Also, somehow for the 1000th try now it's a sucess, so I can't share it. Next time I'll start there.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64579/why-does-adding-a-curve-modifier-move-my-object-to-the-center-of-the-curve/64581#64581 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106587/curve-modifier-does-not-work-when-you-merge-another-curve-to-the-original-curve/106593#106593 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/mesh-deforming-when-add-bezier-modifier/51913#51913

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat/71788 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion/56352