# Follow path constraint location

Tags: animation, constraints

Whenever I apply the follow path constraint to an object and a path, the object totally changes location to a way far away location.

How can I make it so the object doesn’t move it’s location at all when I apply the constraint.

I tried making the path origin in the same spot is the object origin but that still doesn’t work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/

Answer (score 3):

- First you need to put the curve origin at the point where you want the object animation to begin, so do it in *Edit* mode with some <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
- You also need to be sure, in *Edit* mode, that the curve normals go in the right direction. If it's not the case, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*.
- And at last, you have to keep in mind that the position of the object with the *Follow Path* constraint, relatively to the curve origin point, will be its position relatively to the center of the scene (i.e. *Location*). If the object is far from the scene center then, when you'll give it the constraint, it will jump as far from the curve origin as it's far from the scene center. If you press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> it will bring back the object to the 000 location, and therefore at the origin point of the curve.