# Array + Curve modifier deformation in blender 2.81

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

In blender 2.81 the array + curve technique does not work as expected

i've got a hedge with an array modifier and a curve modifier, to make it follow the path i want. It is working just fine in 2.80, but in 2.81 the mesh is completely flat with the exact same settings and when i try to ajust the settings, i just cant achieve the same effect than in 2.80

I hope that there is a way to solve this because i love the new features of 2.81 but with this problem i just cannot use it

[image]

Comment: This is most likely just a case of finding the right rotation for the object and the curve. Try rotating your curve and see how it behave. The curve modifier is very well known to need the right rotation between your mesh and curve to act properly.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/65571#65571