# 2.81: Align objects by specified point

Tags: modeling

I have several arbitrary objects. I need to align them along a line by specified points. I have tried to do it with Origin point, but no success.

Any suggestions?

[image]

**EDIT 1**

"Oscurart Tools" solves the problem but partly. It distributes objects along the straight line only. See the image below :|

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the *Oscurart Tools* addon.
It can align origin points between multiple objects.

1. Enable the addon **✓** in *Preferences > Add-ons*

[image]

2. Select your objects (order matters) and <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Oscurart Tools > Distribute*

*Each cone has origin point in it's tip. After aligning, all the origin points are in line.

(The blue line is just for illustration)*

[image]

Comment: @JACHYM Thank you. But there are 2 points about `Oscurart Tools`: 1 - using this tool I need to align the first and the last object nevertheless, 2 - it doesn't work for curves (see my Edit 1 in the question).

Comment: Hello again :). Aligning along curve is a completely different thing. But these threads could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/161169/78972, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/65571/78972