# curtains with tassels

Tags: cloth-simulation

I modeled curtains for an arcitectural scene now I want to add an edge of small tassels to the curtains. I tried selecting the edge of the curtain, converting it to a curve and arraying the tassel and using a curve modifier. But it doesn't look right since the tassels stick right out and doesn't hang. is there another way to do this?  ... this is the method I used to make the curtains https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUGg5inojss

and this is the look I'm going for:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Maybe related?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161181/35559)