# Array along curve only arrays to a certain distance

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I want to array along a curve, but the array modifier only works to a certain distance (really short). [image]

I've played with different modifiers, but it doesn't seem to work. Also I changed the location and rotation of the elements (the cylinders), but it still arrays to the distance below.
[image]

Here is the increased distance between them... still not working.

https://we.tl/t-bQCNDR5D8n

I'm sending the file via WeTransfer.

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale of your object:

[image]