# Blender array problem

Tags: modeling

I have a problem with array. I'am getting this: [image]

But i need this: [image]

How to fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: Is this rotation and scale that I need to apply: [image]

How to do it in my example?

Comment: Make sure you've applied scale and rotation to your object and that it's origin is at the world origin. Change the type from 'Fixed Count' to 'Fit Curve.'  If that doesn't help, post updated screenshots and maybe your actual blend file.

Comment: How do I apply scale and rotation to object?

Comment: also appears your curve is not a continuous circle like the reference

Comment: How do I make it a continuous circle like the reference?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/65571#65571