# When I use a curve on an object it goes extremely far away from its origin/axes

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

[image: My problem]

When I go into edit mode or delete my curve it goes back to normal. I can't change the origin point because when I do *Selected to Cursor* the actual origin point goes even farther away. But when I do cursor to selected, it sends the 3D cursor to the already existing origin point.

It is different from [Problems with Curve Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier) because I am not trying to do the same thing. My question has to do with *Origin Points*.

Comment: Not enough information! Please share your file:  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: n time of assigning curve to object, origins of both objects has to be at the same location. John is right, we know too little how curve is used ,,,

Answer (score 0):

During the follow path phase of animation the object has to have its Loc transforms set to 0,0,0.

If your mesh has its origin point far from where it should be, put the 3D cursor where you need (you can select a vertex, an edge or a face and press Shift S > cursor to selected), then in object mode right click and choose Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor.

Go to the start, press Alt G to reset the loc, insert a keyframe on the object. Do the same at the end and delete any Loc Keyframe between start and end.

Comment: I edited my answer.