# Peeling apple like faces

Tags: transforms

Goal
: Making animation of opening box that looks like peeling an apple.

Problem
: I used curve modifier to realize this but the side face does not transform what I intendeded to. I used vertex group to affect the first face but how can I affect the another faces? If I tried to, it affects strangely..

Any advice whould be appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image: Peeling apple]

[image]

Comment: Curve modifier does not work the way you would like it to. It makes the whole object deform along the curve at once, so even if you add all the parts you want to deform to the limiting vertex group, whole geometry will deform at once, not the path around the object. You need to use different technique to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hello, could you please explain what you're trying to achieve with a storyboard?

Comment: i also don't get it. Your "desired result" photo is what you got with your blend file...so...i agree with moonboots.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier