# How can I place objects along curve without deform?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to place the same objects along a curve, however when I do this is also deforms every object.

How can I place objects along curve without deform?

I also don’t understand why the objects are not ON the curve, but basically 'jump' to a different location - see the second picture. I set the origin to geometry.

Here is the blend file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did u apply rotation and scale? if yes, pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: I added the file!

Comment: problem 1 you can solve by selecting your object and press alt - g -> both (curve + object) should have the same origin

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/65571#65571

Comment: @Chris I am not sure if I understand what you mean? How can they both have the same origin? Both of them have their origin at the centre of their geometry.

Comment: the origin has to be the same value, else it will look weird. You can also check the answer Duarte linked to it.

Comment: And if you don't want the instances to be deformed, use another method (array a plane, enable its Instancing > Faces option, parent the object that is supposed to be instanced to this plane)