# My Array doesn't follow the curve

Tags: modifiers

I know this is questioned a lot. I have been tried many ways but my stitch array doesn't follow the curve well. I have set curve & object origin to cursor. But still it apply very weirdly. with the huge distance and not following shape between curve & array.

I have also tried Ctrl+A - All transform and it is not work too.
Does anyone has idea what is going on?

What could be wrong is when I move obejct, it goes opposite way also when curve modifier applied. (If you move to right, it goes left.)

Hope someone knows this issue.

enter image description here
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/65571/19307

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WzEqQkbn" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WzEqQkbn/)

Here you are. actually I need to put stitch on the curve(Plane.021) Do you mind to try with that curve?

Comment: the "stitch" origin is probably in the wrong location. If you have applied all transformations to the curve then its origin is at (0,0,0). Deactivate all modifiers of the stitch object so you can see it, then move it to (0,0,0) and apply the location so the origin is also at (0,0,0). Align the object to the X or Y axis, apply the Rotation. Finally, set the used axis in the *Curve* modifier setting.

Answer (score 0):

Both the origin of the curve and of the object are too far from the objects, select them and right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*, then select the curve, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Select*, select the object, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*:

[image]

Second problem: As you see the radius of the cuve vertices is not 1, it has been scaled when you've applied the scale of the curve, bring it back to 1, if you do it through right click > *Set Curve Radius* you need to type 1 then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! now it works with circle line. but I tried with same method on the shoes (stitch needs to be Plane.021). and it doesn´t work :(

Comment: I finally made object to follow curve.
First, I did all transformation at 0,0,0. then made both Origin to Geometric, Curve Cursor to selected, Object origin to cursor.

But somehow objects to follow curve has changed the form and they are extremely thin now. nothing look like original object. is this normal?

Comment: Make sure that the radius of the vertices of your curve are set to 1 (in Edit mode select all, right click > Set Curve Radius, type 1 and Enter)

Comment: Yes, it's currently 1. If the shape of thread is "O" more less, the result is "I". no matter if I increase the stitch obejct thickness or not, it doesn't apply to the curve at all. I'm so sorry for the a lot of issue.

Comment: Could you please share the file with the new problem?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BLdD8zGz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BLdD8zGz/) 
Thank you so much for having a look!

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Mate, Just solved out the problem following your comment. I truly appreciate to your assist. Wish you a best.