# Why does applying a bezier curve modifier flip my object?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

So I have an object here, just a simple rectangle, you can see that objects wireframe mesh below
[image: cube mesh]

Now what I want to do is turn this object into a curving ramp of some sorts, I have a bezier curve following the exact path that I want the rectangle to deform on.
[image: bezier curve]

However, when I apply a curve modifier with the bezier curve, the object flips 90 degrees along the Y axis, the result is below.

[image: result]

How did this happen? Where was the rotation added as a part of the modifier process?

Blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/23XZb3Nb

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/65571/19307

Comment: I've downloaded your file and applied the modifier. All worked fine: no unexpected rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Curve* modifier will deform the object along the Y axis if you set Deform Axis to (positive) Y.

However it has to orient one of the other axes of the object along the normals of the Curve. In this case it picked the object Z axis, which is why the result is rotated 90 degrees.

You can resolve this by adjusting the normals orientation using the curve tilt.

In *Curve Edit Mode* - Select all control points and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (same as accessing the menu *Control Points > Tilt*)

Observe what happens with the deformed object when you move your mouse.
If you type 90 when tilting you will set the tilt of the curve to 90 degrees, which will align the Normal direction of the points with the Z axis of your object. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

You can preview the normals of the curves in *Edit Mode* by toggling on the *Normals* checkbox in *Curve Edit Mode Overlays*.

Comment: Thank you, got it working now, deforming along the correct axis (Y) just as I wanted.