# Can anyone tell me how to modify a cylinder into a spiral using a spiral Bezier curve on Blender?

Tags: mesh, objects, bezier-curves

I am trying to create a spiral object using a spiral shaped Bezier curve. My initial object is a cylinder and I am using curve modifier to do so. I have tried to change the axes as well, but nothing seems to be working. I tried curve modifier, moving, scaling and transforming the object. But the cylinder is not taking the shape of the Bezier curve.
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I cannot see any origin points of the objects or how they are oriented. Getting them correct is very important for this to work. See my answer on this question: [Curve Mod: Object not following Curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310816/curve-mod-object-not-following-curve)

Comment: Is it important to your process to take a base shape and deform it into a spiral, or do you just have an end goal of the spiral tube shape and it's unimportant what steps you take to get there?

Comment: Looks like more than one problem, without a share as recommended by moonboots, we're unlikely to be able to give a definite answer.