# Applying a deform curve modifier to a timing belt

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I'm trying to model a timing belt to drive the print head of a 3D printer. When applying a Deform > Curve modifier to the timing belt, using the BezierCurve, the timing belt disappears from view.

[image]

It is maybe relevent to explain how the motion works:

- There is an empty sphere named "Print target" which is animated by drivers
- There is an invisible X-slider following the XY-coordinates of the print target using a copy location constraint
- There is also an invisible Y-slider following only the Y-coordinate of the Print target using a location constraint
- Some pulleys are parented to the Y-slider
- The corresponding nodes of the BezierCurve are also linked to the Y-slider using a Hook-empty modifier (ctrl-H) in edit mode
  The animation of the BezierCurve works well. In a later stage, I was planning to move the timing belt along the curve by copying the location of the X-slider.

Here's what I tried to make the Curve modifier work:

- I measured the length of the BezierCurve using the Curve Tools Add-on, and matched the length of the timing belt accordingly.
- I applied scaling and location of the timing belt and the bezier curve
- I removed the Hook-empty modifier of the BezierCurve
- I moved both the start of the Timing Belt and the starting node of the BezierCurve to the global origin and applied all transformations
- I fiddled with the deform axis in the Curve modifier

I removed and added the Curve modifier to the timing belt after each step. The curve modifier is still applied, but not displayed in the viewport.

It would be great if someone could help me visualize the deformed timing belt.

Thanks,

HenkJan

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/

Comment: Hi, HenkJan.. welcome. At some point, you have set your curve's radius to 0, so the deformed geometry is also scaled to 0, across the curve's tangent.  Set the radius back to 1, (N Panel) in Edit Mode, all selected, and it looks fine. I think this is covered in @Duarte's link, so it's  fair to call this  a duplicate post.