Array and Curve modifier difficulty
I'm trying to make stitching for this shoe.  I'm using the array and curve modifiers to try and do so but I am not able to get it to work.  As you can see in the picture I've gotten the other stitching to work using the same method, by essentially fudging it, but this larger stitch isn't wanting to be fudged.  I've set the origin of the curve at the point where I want the stitching to start, moved the 3D cursor to the origin, set the origin of the starting stitch to its center of mass, moved it to the 3D cursor, applied rotation and scale, then added the modifiers.  After this, I would just move the arrayed stitch mesh around until it fit, but it is moving in all the wrong directions.

Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/65571#65571

Here is another overview on how the Curve modifier places array objects: Curve Modifier- not starting at beginning

@Nathan I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you say there (or if a beginner understands it correctly): "Start by moving the stitch to the location of the first curve control." What do you mean, the stitch in Object Mode with its origin to the first curve control (point?) or to the origin of the curve? Because it sounds as if you mean moving the stitch origin to the control point.

@Nathan What do you move to eye? In the screenshot, the curve seems to be placed where the stitch should be. So when curve and stitch object have the same origin and the mesh is located correctly relative to its origin, there is no need for moving it to eye and it will be arrayed exactly on the curve.

@Nathan I wasn't talking about the location or rotation - they have to match on both objects. But then there is no need to move the mesh around with try and error: when the stitch mesh is placed centered on the origin in local Y and Z and extends from local X = 0 to +X, then the stitches will exactly follow the curve starting at the first control point. And even when the curve's first control point is not at the origin. That's why it sounded weird to me that you want to move the mesh to the first control point.

@GordonBrinkmann Oh, I see what you're saying now.  Yeah, I didn't word things properly.  I'll delete.
